# How to set Intent and Configuration before starting activity in Robolectric

Tags: android, android-intent, android-resources, robolectric, android-testing

My Activity -that i want to test- has to have extras before starting which had to be located in Intent. How can i add them before lunching the activity in testing?

And the same function is also needed to set the "Locale" in "Configuration" in Activity.

I think that we have to use shadowActivity but i could not find any example for that.

Please help & Thank you!

Comment: Or is it not possible? Since 22 hours i could not find any example to realize it.

Comment: Check [this response][1] for a way to do this in Robolectric 2.x 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17195761/robolectric-2-create-activity-with-intent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About the extras, I don't see any problem. Just create a new Intent, put all the extras and set in our activity.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra(..,..);
activity.setIntent(intent);
activity.onCreate(null);
```

Comment: I was using the version 0.9.4. In this case, it has no any effect. But what you write is valid only for versions above 2.x.

Comment: But why are you using a version so old? The new version is better in any way! I have to admit that was very difficult the first configuration, you know, to make the tests run in a ant build in a android app with multi projects. But after that... was all happiness!