# robolectric 2 - create activity with intent

Tags: robolectric

Does creating an activity using the `.withIntent()` not work in Robolectric 2? I'm doing the following

```
    activity = Robolectric.buildActivity(MyActivity.class)
                            .create()
                            .withIntent(intent)
                            .get();
```

And i'm getting a `NullPointerException` when doing the following in the `onCreate()` of my activity.

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
```

I can code a null check in my `onCreate()` and set the intent by doing the following but it seems redundant to set the intent and call the `onCreate()` method again when Robolectric already does that when creating the `Activity` instance. This seems like an unnecessary work around.

```
    Robolectric.shadowOf(activity).setIntent(intent);
    activity.onCreate(null);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out my problem. I wasn't instantiating the `Intent` properly. I was instantiating it with the no-arg constructor when i needed to give a `Context` and the class of the `Activity` it was being sent to

Comment: How do you get a Context?

Comment: What goes here: new Intent(Robolectric.application.getApplicationContext(), ?? )

Comment: ?? should be replaced with the activity being built. So MyActivity.class

Answer (score 6):

This is a case where a fluent-style API kinds of leads you down the wrong path...

You want to:

```
activity = Robolectric.buildActivity(MyActivity.class)
                        .withIntent(intent)
                        .create()
                        .get();
```

so that the intent is provided to the builder before it calls onCreate().

Comment: i tried that already. didn't work for me. `getIntent()` still returned null for me

Comment: It didn't work for me as well so I just extended MyActivity and overrode onCreate. There I called setIntent with a new intent.

Answer (score 6):

For newer versions of Robolectric use `Robolectric.buildActivity(Class, Intent)`.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: It was fixed in version 2.2.

<strike>I tackled with the same issue. It [was reported](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/601) but no fix has been provided yet. For now, I manage to hack it using Activity's setter before calling onCreate(), taking advantage from the fact that its lifecycle has not yet started:</strike>

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
MainActivity mainActivity = Robolectric.buildActivity(MainActivity.class)
                                       .create()
                                       .get();
mainActivity.setIntent(intent);
mainActivity.onCreate(null);
```