# robolectric 2 - create activity under test with intent

Tags: android, robolectric

I am writing unit test with Robolectric. The setup looks like this

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class MiAirlineActivityTest {
    @Before
    public void setUpFor() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(HOW_TO_PASS_CONTEXT_HERE, MiAirlineActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(EMPLOYEEID_EXTRA, "username");

        miAirlineActivity = Robolectric.buildActivity(MiAirlineActivity.class)
                                .withIntent(intent).start().get();
    }
}
```

How to pass the context while creating the new intent.
I followed the example from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17195761/robolectric-2-create-activity-with-intent) question.

There @David says,

> "... i needed to give a Context and the class of the Activity it was being sent to"

How exactly I can do that ?

Note: Please don't mark it as duplicate of the above linked question. I am asking a new question since I could not add comment there.

Comment: possible duplicate of [robolectric 2 - create activity with intent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17195761/robolectric-2-create-activity-with-intent)

Answer (score 9):

Try this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Robolectric.getShadowApplication().getApplicationContext(),
                MiAirlineActivity.class);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
miAirlineActivity = Robolectric.buildActivity(MiAirlineActivity.class).create().get();
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra(EMPLOYEEID_EXTRA, "username");
miAirlineActivity.setIntent(intent);
miAirlineActivity.onCreate(new Bundle());
```

This will launch your activity with the desired intent

Comment: thanks @user2483079, but the solution is giving error:

`testSetBasketForExistingSeatWhoHasDeferredPurchases(com.miairline.activities.MiAirlineActivityTest)  Time elapsed: 1.375 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.miairline.activities.MiAirlineActivity.onCreate(MiAirlineActivity.java:540)`

this is the point where the code has called getIntent() and the intent is null.

Comment: In my case I only called .get then it worked. thanks @user2483079

Answer (score 2):

Build your activity with an intent

```
Intent intent = new Intent(HOW_TO_PASS_CONTEXT_HERE,MiAirlineActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(EMPLOYEEID_EXTRA, "username");
iAirlineActivity = Robolectric.buildActivity(MiAirlineActivity.class).withIntent(intent).create().get();
```

look at the roboelectric docs [here](http://robolectric.org/activity-lifecycle/)

Answer (score 2):

I am posting this because when I google "android roboelectric 3 buildactivity intent", this page is top result.

```
testImplementation "org.robolectric:robolectric:3.7.1"
```

withIntent() is no longer available in robolectric 3.

I used the code below:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(HOW_TO_PASS_CONTEXT_HERE,MiAirlineActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(EMPLOYEEID_EXTRA, "username");
iAirlineActivity = Robolectric.buildActivity(MiAirlineActivity.class,intent).create().get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Intent intent = new Intent(ShadowApplication.getInstance().getApplicationContext(), Activity.class);

Comment: Please format your code and add an explanation to help explain the benefit of this answer vs others.

Answer (score 0):

No need to create the context and target Activity class by using the constructor. Try this:

```
@Before
public void setUpFor() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra(EMPLOYEEID_EXTRA, "username");

    miAirlineActivity = Robolectric.buildActivity(MiAirlineActivity.class)
                            .withIntent(intent).start().get();
}
```